# Is that possible with <!DOCTYPE html><html> tag at starting cause css and js not load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project for envato market and i am stucked at 1 one point, On localhost and webserver everything is working fine here is my css & js for localhost and webserver

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <meta name="description" content="Admin Panel">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
**************Some Content********************
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/errorMsg.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Eventually I forgot at the top

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Problem is on reviewer testing environment CSS & JS is not loading here is the screenshot https://envato.d.pr/a7qHAK

I want to ask is it possible it is the reason not to load CSS & JS file on their system, I worried because how its working fine on my localhost XAMPP & webserver.

Any help will be appreciated

Here is my network tab screenshot
[image]

Comment: what's the directory structure of your project? You may be reffering to the wrong directory?

Comment: all the css and js files in admin folder and index file also in admin folder, if i referred wrong path its definitely will not work on localhost & webserver

Comment: No, the broswers now smart enough to parse and add those for you, although its not a valid HTML, your issue seems that you are not including the right path for your CSS/JS files.

Comment: My assumption is that you are on a page that is not in the root of your website, but you are using URLs relative to the current page, so they resolve to a different path than you expect. Check the network tab in the browser to see the (failed) network requests, and you'll see what I mean. You should use root-relative URLs probably, by adding a slash in front of the path.

Comment: but i am using correct path, all css files in css folder and all js files in js folder and index file in admin folder, calling cs/main.js , even on server i open directly copy and paste those file url and it opens

Comment: But if you are for example on `http://example.com/a/b/c/d` then `css/test.css` will resolve to `http://example.com/a/b/c/css/test.css` and not `http://example.com/css/test.css` (which could be fixed by using `/css/test.css` instead). Did you do what I said and checked the network tab in your browser's devtools, looking for those requests?

Comment: i am getting status 304 in network tab , what should i do

Comment: Note that it also makes a difference whether your current url has a trailing slash or not. In my previous example, if you were on `http://example.com/a/b/c/d/` instead of `http://example.com/a/b/c/d`, it would resolve to `http://example.com/a/b/c/d/css/test.css` instead of `http://example.com/a/b/c/css/test.css`

Comment: 304 is correct. It means the resource was found and loaded from cache because it didn't change.

Comment: Wait a second, your previous screenshot showed 404 (not found), not 304. Are you sure you are looking at the right requests?

Comment: this is the biggest question for me and i am stucked why on reviewer system cannot find resource css and js file

Comment: Again, did you check the URLs in the network tab for the CSS requests? Maybe show a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215458/discussion-between-cherrydt-and-amrit-jha).

Comment: i am telling you 1 thing my last item was approved and this is same css and js , this time in soft reject due to resource not loading and i found that at top i missed <!DOCTYPE html><html> but at end i am closing , is this a problem to not load css and js ?

Comment: i have read about quirks mode , it is possible if reviewer OS is mac and without <!DOCTYPE html> cause problem to not to load css and js file ?